# Xamarin.Android-The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I get the above error while building my project.The context the methods are referring to are different,so i don't know what's causing the error.I have a file browsing feature in the app.So depending on which activity called the browser,the user can select a folder or a file and it's path returned.

```
public class FileListAdapter : ArrayAdapter<FileSystemInfo>
{

private readonly Context _context;

    public FileListAdapter(Context context, IList<FileSystemInfo> fsi)
        : base(context, Resource.Layout.file_picker_list_item, Android.Resource.Id.Text1, fsi)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var fileSystemEntry = GetItem(position);

        FileListRowViewHolder viewHolder;
        View row;



        if (convertView == null)
        {
            row = _context.GetLayoutInflater().Inflate(Resource.Layout.file_picker_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new FileListRowViewHolder(row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.file_picker_text), row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.file_picker_image));
            row.Tag = viewHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            row = convertView;
            viewHolder = (FileListRowViewHolder)row.Tag;
        }
        viewHolder.Update(fileSystemEntry.Name, fileSystemEntry.IsDirectory() ? Resource.Drawable.folder : Resource.Drawable.file);

        return row;
    }



}
```

Second class:

```
public class FolderListAdapter : ArrayAdapter<DirectoryInfo>
{
   public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

private readonly Context _context;


    public FolderListAdapter(Context context, IList<DirectoryInfo> fsi)
        : base(context, Resource.Layout.file_picker_list_item, Android.Resource.Id.Text1, fsi)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
        var fileSystemEntry = GetItem(position);

        FileListRowViewHolder viewHolder;
        View view = convertView;



        if (convertView == null)
        {
            view = _context.GetLayoutInflater().Inflate(Resource.Layout.folder_picker_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new FileListRowViewHolder(view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.folder_picker_text), view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.folder_picker_image));
            view.Tag = viewHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            view = convertView;
            viewHolder = (FileListRowViewHolder)view.Tag;
        }
        viewHolder.Update(fileSystemEntry.Name, fileSystemEntry.IsDirectory() ? Resource.Drawable.folder : Resource.Drawable.file);

        return view;
    }


}
```

The error appears on these lines in both classes:

```
                view = _context.GetLayoutInflater().Inflate(Resource.Layout.folder_picker_list_item, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the build error.It was such a small issue.The context was the problem.So i simply changed the 'Context in question' to point to the Activity.From this:

```
public static LayoutInflater GetLayoutInflater(this Context context)
    {
        return context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService).JavaCast<LayoutInflater>();


    }
```

To this :

```
public static LayoutInflater GetLayoutInflater(Activity context)
    {
        return context.GetSystemService(Activity.LayoutInflaterService).JavaCast<LayoutInflater>();
    }
```